# Font licensing of New Century Schoolbook

Tags: fonts, licensing

Can I use the New Century Schoolbook (\usepackage{fouriernc}) font for my bachelor thesis without any copyright issues?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This site does not treat legal issues, which can vary from country to country. The fonts you mention are provided by TeX Live, so their state as free software is quite likely.

Comment: @egreg Why do we have a [tag:licensing] tag then?

Comment: This is a legal question and, hence, off-topic. @HenriMenke 'Which licence should I use for my package, if I want it included in TeX Live?' is probably OK. They have a policy which clearly allows certainly licences. But I agree, we should probably better not have the tag at all.

Comment: I am not a lawyer. This is not legal advice. However, you are asking the wrong question, probably. There is not likely to be a copyright issue arising from the font you use. More likely licensing issues. Certainly, if you are concerned about legal issues from font use, these should include licensing ones. But, as I say, you should take this with a pinch of salt as I'm not a lawyer and, if I were, there is no reason to think I'd be familiar with your jurisdiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in doubt, you can always use a font from the TeX Gyre collection of fonts.  In this case you will want to use TeX Gyre Schola which is derived from URW Century Schoolbook L.

The TeX Gyre fonts are licensed under the [GUST Font License (GFL)](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/licenses).  In particular it grants

> “The freedoms granted by GFL include the free use of the fonts for whatever purpose you wish.”<sup>[(source)](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/index_html#Licensing)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

[CTAN page](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fouriernc?lang=en) has licensing information.

> Licence: This material is subject to the LaTeX Project Public License.
>   See http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/licenses.lppl.html
>   for the details of that license.